# How can i get the url from the string by using regular expression or any javascript method

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

```
    [
    "<iframe allowFullScreen frameborder=\"0\" height=\"564\" mozallowfullscreen src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360\" webkitAllowFullScreen width=\"640\"></iframe>"
]
```

How can i get the below url from the above ptr string using reg exp:
[https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360\](https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360%5C)
I am trying to split string but not able to get the url.

```
ptr.split(/(?=:)/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a URL from a string using the following RegExp:

```js
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/
```

So to get the URL from that string:

```js
const ptr = '<iframe allowFullScreen frameborder="0" height="564" mozallowfullscreen src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360" webkitAllowFullScreen width="640"></iframe>'

const url = /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/.exec(ptr)[0];
```

When using `RegExp.prototype.exec()` you, the first element in the returned array is the full string that was matched, in this case `https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360`. You can also remove the `[0]` from the end of the `url` expression to get the full returned array in case you need other information about the match.

See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for more details on the `RegExp.exec` function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can leverage the DOM API and do like;

```js
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    src;

div.innerHTML = "<iframe allowFullScreen frameborder=\"0\" height=\"564\" mozallowfullscreen src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/253266360\" webkitAllowFullScreen width=\"640\"></iframe>";
src = div.firstChild.src;

console.log(src);
```